# how to delay escalation to sig-term after sending sig-int to roslaunch

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I control-c a roslaunch command, each node is terminated first with sig-ints.  If the node fails to die after 10 seconds, sig-int is escalated to sig-term.  Is there a way to stop or delay this escalation from happening?

This is useful when debugging examples like [this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/2315/how-can-i-speed-up-the-shutdown-of-gazebo-with).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11353/how-to-delay-escalation-to-sig-term-after-sending-sig-int-to-roslaunch/) by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5780 on 2011-09-28

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Right now this delay is not configurable, so changing this behavior means editing pmon.py in roslaunch directly.  It would be a good future enhancement to make roslaunch more configurable.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-10-11**:
looks like that's nodeprocess.py rather than pymon.py.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-30**:
pmon.py will work for now.  Thanks.

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2018-08-23**:
https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1493

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For kinetic this can be found in:

> /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch

In the file nodeprocess.py there will be 2 variables on line 57 and 58.

> _TIMEOUT_SIGINT = 15.0 #seconds

> _TIMEOUT_SIGTERM = 2.0 #seconds

change these if needed

---

Originally posted by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) with karma: 171 on 2016-10-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4